# AngularJS + AngularFire = How to edit entry

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularfire, ionic-framework

My `$scope` has:

`$scope.current_account_key` - key from my update modal

`$scope.current_account` which has a name: `$scope.current_account.name`, and a description `$scope.current_account.description` (account is my entry)

I want to update an entry in Firebase with these values.

Firebase tree:

```
accounts
    -JL7e0Obv18-Ls6TTkk8
        description
        name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in two ways.

You can get accounts and get the specific child and update and save the child

```
var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl + '/accounts');
var accounts = $firebase(ref);

var child = accounts.$child(key);
// Set any value to child and save
// child.name = 'changed name';
child.$save();
```

(Or)

Get the child element directly

```
var ref = new Firebase(fbUrl + '/accounts/' + key);
$scope.account = $firebase(ref);

// Set any value to account and save
// account.name = 'changed name';
$scope.account.$save();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I had discovered some bugs in my view, but this is working like a charm (I was trying something similar but without any luck). Thank you one more time.

Comment: I have just one another little question. The tree is same for category and record (like accounts). What is the best practice if I want to click on category, which gives me all records? Records belongs to category and category belongs to account. Now I have for example category with these paramaters:


category.name, category.description and category.account (which stores key of account).